# Set value from a global object to a radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a radio buttons group to a given property from an object. Using such code

```
<span><input type="radio" value="{{webTES.TripLegType.TimeCall}}" ng-model="tab.Type"/>Time Call</span>
                                    <br/>
<span><input type="radio" value="{{webTES.TripLegType.Immediate}}" ng-model="tab.Type"/>Immediate</span>
                                    <br/>
<span><input type="radio" value="{{webTES.TripLegType.WillCall}}" ng-model="tab.Type"/>Will Call</span>
```

binding to prorpety works, but I also need to set the values for those radio buttons from a global object which is used across app. The object is defined like this

```
var webTES = {
    TripLegType: {
        TimeCall: 0,
        Immediate: 1,
        WillCall: 2
    }
};
```

I tried to use `{{}}` but it won't work and I'd hate to use hard-coded constants.

How do I solve this nicely?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the global on the scope and set the radio button values with `ngValue`:

Controller

```
$scope.webTES = webTES;
```

View

```
<span>
    <input type="radio" ng-value="webTES.TripLegType.TimeCall" ng-model="tab.Type"/>
    Time Call
</span>
<br />
<span>
    <input type="radio" ng-value="webTES.TripLegType.Immediate" ng-model="tab.Type"/>
    Immediate
</span>
<br />
<span>
    <input type="radio" ng-value="webTES.TripLegType.WillCall" ng-model="tab.Type"/>
    Will Call
</span>
```

Comment: `value="{{webTES.TripLegType.TimeCall}}"` works fine.  adding webTES to scope is all that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to access it from outside your Angular app, you can use a `value`

```
angular.module('moduleName')
  .value('webTES', {
    TripLegType: {
      TimeCall: 0,
      Immediate: 1,
      WillCall: 2
    }
  });
```

That way, it won't be hanging on the window object. It can then be injected by name into your `controller` and you can put it on `$scope` where the template can find it. If you want to configure it when the application load, use a `constant`. You can read about values and constants [here](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/).